# Make absolutely positioned child element force visible on overflow hidden parent element?

Tags: css, overflow, hidden

Is there any way to make absolutely positioned child element force visible  on overflow hidden parent element ?. Below is the code snippet I was trying .

```
div{
    position: relative;
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    overflow: hidden;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
}

div span{
    position: absolute;
    top: 10px;
    right: -25px;
    display: block;
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    background: #444;
}

div p{
    padding: 10px;
}

<div>
    <span></span>
    <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged.</p>
</div>
```

Here is the fiddle link http://jsfiddle.net/2m93zbhL/

Comment: I have also tried using CSS  'clearfix' but not seems working [link](http://jsfiddle.net/ymdsm83f/2/)

Answer (score 1):

No it's not.

Just add another div :

```
<div class="wrapper">
        <span></span>
        <div class="container">
            <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged.</p>
        </div>
    </div>
```

And put the "overflow:hidden" property on the inside div :

```
.wrapper{
        position: relative;
        width: 200px;
        height: 200px;
        border: 1px solid #ccc;
    }

    .container{
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
        bottom: 0;
        width: 100%;
        overflow: hidden;
    }

    .wrapper span{
        position: absolute;
        top: 10px;
        right: -25px;
        display: block;
        width: 50px;
        height: 50px;
        background: #444;
    }
```

See this fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/2m93zbhL/1/